# Dsiplay MatChips only if the observable has less then nine entries

Tags: angular, observable, angular-ng-if

I have a mat-chip-list with an ngFor and the matchips shall only be displayed if the array of my observable has less then nine entries.

This is my HTML:

```
<mat-chip-list *ngIf="selectedAttributes$ | async as attributes">
  <div *ngFor="let attribute of attributes">
    <mat-chip *ngIf="attribute.isSelected">{{attribute.label}}
      <button matChipRemove
        (click)="onChipClose(attribute.label)">
        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-chip>
  </div>
</mat-chip-list>
```

This is my Obserable:

```
 selectedAttributes$: Observable<SearchSettings[]> = this.searchSettingsService.searchSettings$;
```

I tried to add another div with an if condition like this:

```
*ngIf="(selectedAttributes$ |async)?.lenght < 9"
```

but it did not work out.

Comment: `*ngIf="(selectedAttributes$ | async)?.length < 9"` should work. There was a typo in your `*ngIf` statement, could that be the case?

Comment: The typo was my mistake. It does work but my condition seems to be the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedAttributes$ | async as attributes"
 <mat-chip-list *ngIf="attributes.length < 9">
  <div *ngFor="let attribute of attributes">
    <mat-chip *ngIf="attribute.isSelected">{{attribute.label}}
      <button matChipRemove
        (click)="onChipClose(attribute.label)">
        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-chip>
  </div>
 </mat-chip-list>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: is there a reason to use ng-container over a div?

Comment: yes a `ng-container` does not add an extra dom element while div does